# How can i connect to MYSQL database using SSH tunneling from NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, ssh-tunnel

Note:

1. I am using password for authentication to SSH server.
2. Running Windows OS.
3. Also need to deploy the application in **Heroku** later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  used [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh) npm package to creating a tunnel and then successfully created mysql connection.

Later, when I deployed my app to Heroku, everything was working fine.